# Google Codejam Milkshake Example: Cannot Find The Mistake

Tags: python

I am practicing these problems:
http://code.google.com/codejam/contest/32016/dashboard#s=p1&a=1

I believe I have the correct solution, (even after manual inspection of input and output);
still I keep getting `Incorrect Output`

Could anyone point out where I could be wrong?

```
def process_file(file):
    fsock = open(file)
    text = fsock.read()
    fsock.close()
    lines = text.split('\n')
    return lines


def process_lines(lines):
    cur = 1
    ans = []
    while cur < len(lines) - 1:
        N = int(lines[cur])
        cur += 1
        M = int(lines[cur])
        cur += 1
        struct = []
        for i in range(0, M):
            cust_pref = [int(n) for n in lines[cur].split(' ')]
            cust_drinks = [a-1 for a in cust_pref[1::2]]
            cust_drinks_malt_pref = cust_pref[2::2]
            cust_choice = [(cust_drinks[i], cust_drinks_malt_pref[i]) for i in range(0, len(cust_drinks))]
            cur += 1
            struct.append(cust_choice)
        ans.append((N, struct))
    return ans


def process_case(case):
    milkshake_menu = [0] * case[0] # our default menu
    i = 0
    impossible = False
    while i < len(case[1]): # i represents the customer number, case[1] represents customers
        acceptable = False
        customer = case[1][i]
        for drink_preferred in customer:
            if milkshake_menu[drink_preferred[0]] == drink_preferred[1]:
                acceptable = True
                i += 1 # ok, next customer
                break
        if not acceptable:
            for drink_preferred in customer:
                # find a malted preference
                if drink_preferred[1] == 1 and milkshake_menu[drink_preferred[0]] != 1:
                    # he needs a malted one
                    milkshake_menu[drink_preferred[0]] = 1
                    # but then we have to test previous customers, reset i
                    i = 0
                    break
                #if you have come here, the customer does not have a malted preference, or has a unmalted preference that conflicts with other customer
                impossible = True
            #impossible is True, break outer loop
            if impossible:
                break
    if impossible:
       return "IMPOSSIBLE"
    else:
       return " ".join([str(n) for n in milkshake_menu])



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    filename = sys.argv[1]
    lines = process_file(filename)
    inp = process_lines(lines)
    for k, v in enumerate(inp):
        a = process_case(v)
        print "Case #%d: %s" % (k + 1, a)
```

Pastebin Output: http://pastebin.com/uXJQKbSr

Comment: That's not how SO works. Please read the [faq] and [ask].

Comment: Have you tried it on the sample data? Does it work?

Comment: Yes it outputs a valid answer. Should I post that too?

Comment: @Jim Garrison :: I think I have a legit problem, I am not able to see through it (and this is not homework)

Comment: Your question is of the form "here's my code, tell me what's wrong", which is off-topic.  If show your output and explain why you think it should be correct, you'll go a long way towards fitting within the guidelines.

Comment: @Jim Garrison: Thanks, have attached pastebin link to output. The codejam page details the exact problem (too verbose for here)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing that looks odd is in the loop

```
        for drink_preferred in customer:
            # find a malted preference
            if drink_preferred[1] == 1 and milkshake_menu[drink_preferred[0]] != 1:
                # he needs a malted one
                milkshake_menu[drink_preferred[0]] = 1
                # but then we have to test previous customers, reset i
                i = 0
                break
            impossible = True
```

I would expect this to be

```
        for drink_preferred in customer:
            # find a malted preference
            if drink_preferred[1] == 1 and milkshake_menu[drink_preferred[0]] != 1:
                # he needs a malted one
                milkshake_menu[drink_preferred[0]] = 1
                # but then we have to test previous customers, reset i
                i = 0
                break
        else:
            impossible = True
```

I think at the moment you will judge the task is impossible before having checked all the possibilities.

Comment: Thanks, that was where it was wrong. Though I always thought that if..else.. always had the same indentation levels: must consult documentation...

Comment: You are quite right that if and else have the same indentation.  In this example the else is linked to the for loop.  The meaning is that if the for loop reaches the end (i.e. without getting to a break) it will execute the else clause.